# Godot: How do I asign movement cost to tiles in a Tilemap?

Tags: path-finding, platformer, godot

**Pathfinding**

I am trying to apply godot's Navigation to create a pahtfinding enemy in a Platformer game. I've read about a method to allow for pathfinding to take into account gravity.

My issue is that what I know I must do is to add more movement cost to higher tiles.

How do I do this?

**EDIT**

I have since found the documentation for the [Astar Node](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.0/classes/class_astar.html). Wish me luck.

Comment: Rather than an edit, post an answer so it can be closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Astar Node**

Godot has an [Astar](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.0/classes/class_astar.html) node for pathfinding.